# Gettign the error :Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from jaxb

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to do

```
java -jar jaxb-api-1.5.jar
```

I am getting the following error :

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest
>   attribute from jaxb-api-1.5.jar

I am running it in jdk1.4 env.

Why this is happening and how can it be recitified ?

What i am trying to do is generate the classes from xsd using jaxb xjc command in jdk1.4 env. If there is other way then please let me know
Any pointer will help
Thank

Comment: i tried same in java 5 ,still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded this [jaxb-api-1.5.jar](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/versionInfo/41965) and its MANIFEST.MF does not contain any Main-Class attribute in deed. I think this jar is not intended to be executed via `java -jar` call.

There are some resouces on the [JAXB site](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/index.html). You can download the latest stable version from [here](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=10151&expandFolder=10151&folderID=0). It contains shell scripts / batch programs to do what you need.

Comment: can you please tell me which version is supported for jdk1.4 .Thanks

Comment: @harshit I don't know if you're not reading this answer very closely, or rather confused, but what he's  basically saying is that this jar is not executable in the say way that a dll is not executable.  This is not a program to be run directly.  It's a library for use by java programmers.